# I have old stock certificates in Antares Resources Corporation. Does this old stock have any value?

Tags: stocks, historical-data

I have a Common Stock certificate for 310 shares of Antares Resources Corporation issued March 24, 1997.  The corporate seal shows a 1958 date. I believe the company changed its name and ticker symbol and may have been delisted at some point.  Is the company still in business and is there any value in the shares I have?

Comment: Bad news, if this is the same company it looks like they went bankrupt: http://www.secinfo.com/$/SEC/Registrant.asp?CIK=65202

Answer (score 3):

Antares Resources was delisted from Nasdaq in Feb 1997 due to it having too low a price (it closed at $1.375 on 4 Feb 1997).

It then went and traded as an OTC stock and did not make any SEC filings until 2006 (apart from a minor filing for issue of securities to employees).  In 19976 SEC queried them about not reporting but there doesn't appear to be any response.

In 2006 the company issued a report, but this was issued by a Chapter 11 (Bankruptcy) Trustee, with no further filings, with practically zero cash balance, so this company would seem to be defunct with no return to shareholders.

Sources:
Stock data from Norgate Data https://norgatedata.com/
SEC filings by Antares Resources https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000065202&owner=exclude&count=40

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that you could try:

- Do a Google search to see if you can track down corporate events that may transpired such as a symbol change or a merger with another company.
- Find a source for OTC BB and Pink Sheets companies and see if there's a current listing there (these are where delisted stocks still in business end up)
- The stock certificate will have the name of the Transfer Agent on it.  Sometimes it also includes their address.  If they are still in existence, contact them to determine the disposition of Antares Resources.  This is probably the most reliable approach.